# Is it compatible to use an Apple iPad with a Windows/HP/Dell/Lenovo laptop?

Tags: ipad, ms-office, compatibility

I would like to buy a laptop which has OneNote facilities for now because Apple's are a bit far expensive for me.

So if I, later on, purchase an Apple iPad, will it be compatible (that is) is it possible to share notes, etc. from laptop to iPad and vice-versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Microsoft office suite apps work very well with iPad. This includes OneDrive, OneNote and we have no issues with people at work with MS Teams integration and collaborative / simultaneous editing of documents across operating systems.

The only “gotcha” would be older OS but support for current and N-1 is very good with Microsoft and Apple.

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling Sir , btw Sir one problem i am suffering from may you like to answer that to , i think it might not be answered here so asked here in comment s: " I want to use touch feature for writing handwritten notes on OneNote in a laptop (which is not touchscreen), is it possible Sir?"

Comment: Why not ask that as a proper question? If the laptop is apple, this site would gladly host that new question.

Comment: Hmm alright Sir